# Deploying database tables in order of relationship with contraints

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I hope I can explain this question correctly.

My ASP.NET project holds a the list of MS SQL Server database table scripts for in-case of future upgrades etc I can just run the script again without having to add new files. Currently I have for each database table:

```
---CREATING TABLE---
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DATABASETABLENAME]') AND type IN (N'U'))
    //CREATE TABLE CODE HERE

---BUILDING RELATIONSHIPS---
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [name] = 'FK_CONSTRAINTNAME') ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DATBASETABLENAME] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_CONSTRAINTNAME]
    //ADD CONSTRAINT CODE HERE
```

My problem is, if the table the constraint is being made with has not had its script run yet, the table does not exist and will fail.

I could do a check if the other constraint table exists, but it would still require running all scripts twice to work.

Without hardcoding, is there a way to identify and order the table scripts running based on their dependancies? e.g in the future there could be hundreds of tables.

Please let me know if this information is not sufficient.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Since you are using ASP.NET, you can try using a Database project in Visual Studio, which handles such issues and automatically generates a build script for the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small algorithm to order the tables based on the constraints but it will not always be possible (imagine you have a circular reference). Better approach would be first to create all the tables and then add the constraints (once all tables are created).

Comment: Thanks, I will just wait a bit to see what other people say. I was hoping not to have to separate the constraints from my table scripts. But I understand the circular reference issue, which i do not currently have but surely will have soon.

Comment: if you do not have circular refs it is just like sorting an array where instead of "t1 < t2" you say "t1 depends on t2"

Comment: Awesome, never thought of doing that!

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer is the fool proof way. I add a 'ScriptVersion' table to my database and I keep track of the update script 'version' that has been applied. In my update scripts I check if the database exists and at what 'version' it is at. If the version number is not right, I print an error message. Here is an exerpt of one of my update scripts:

```
if db_id('[DATABASENAME]') is null
```

begin
    print('The database does not exists: please run the create script.')
end
else
begin
    use [DATABASENAME]

```
if object_id('ScriptVersion', 'U') is null
begin
    print('Database does not contain a Script version table. Please check the upgrade script.')
end
else
begin
    -- check the latest upgrade
    if ((select max(ToVersion) from ScriptVersion) <> 4)
    begin
        print('Invalid upgrade. Check which upgrade to run.');
    end
    else
    begin
        -- START update statements

        exec('alter table Activities add Comments varchar(256)')
        exec('alter table Activities add IsCancelled bit not null default(0)')

        -- END update statements


        -- Insert new script version (update from version #4 to version #5)
        exec('insert into ScriptVersion(Description, FromVersion, ToVersion) values (''Upgrade 5.'', 4, 5)')
    end
end
```

end
go

In your particular situation I might add a 'DependencyName' or DependencyId and IsDependency field to the versioning table (or create a table especially for dependencies) and check if the given dependency exists with a query yes or no.

Comment: Thanks for that. It does not really help me in this instance though. Thank you :)